# Como condicionar a inserção de um registro em SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, tsql, inserir

Como eu posso condicionar a inserção de um registro numa tabela no SQL Server utilizando a linguagem T-SQL considerando as seguintes regras:

- Se o registro a ser inserido já existir na tabela, somente atualizar o campo referente a data de modificação do registro;
- Se o registro ainda não existir, realizar a inserção do mesmo atribuição a data atual no campo referente a data de modificação do registro.

Por exemplo, dada a tabela `DatasBase` com a seguinte estrutura:

```
+--------------------------------------+
|              DatesBase               |
+--------------------------------------+
| PK DateBase        DATETIME NOT NULL |
|    DateAtualizacao DATETIME NOT NULL |
+--------------------------------------+
```

onde, tenho um registro de datas utilizadas numa outra tabela com suas respectivas datas de atualização. Supomos que precisamos inserir a data `'2013-12-12'` nesta tabela, no entanto, se ela já existir na tabela, preciso apenas atualizar o campo `DateAtualizacao`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Você pode usar um [`MERGE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) (disponível a partir do SQL Server 2008):

```sql
MERGE DatasBase AS existentes
USING (SELECT '2013-12-13', '2013-12-14') AS novos (DateBase, DataAtualizacao)
  ON (existentes.DateBase = novos.DateBase)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET DataAtualizacao = novos.DataAtualizacao
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (DateBase, DataAtualizacao)
  VALUES (novos.DateBase, novos.DataAtualizacao);
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/797ae/16

Comment: Me corrijam se eu estive errado, mas acho que essa é a melhor solução pois para o banco é apenas uma operação.

Comment: Acho que no caso de "upsert" de uma linha esta solução deve ser equivalente à do Luiz Ricardo (não entendi a rejeição à resposta dele). No caso de um upsert em lote, minha solução deve ser mais rápida, pois funciona basicamente como um join, não exigindo EXISTS para cada linha.

Comment: [Há quem](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2651/comparing-performance-for-the-merge-statement-to-select-insert-update-or-delete/) ache que o MERGE é um pouco melhor pelo motivo que o @talles mencionou. Note que o MERGE é disponível a partir da versão 2008 do SQL Server, a minha solução não tem essa limitação, mas infelizmente o autor da pergunta não especificou nada a esse respeito.

Comment: Este método não é compatível com todas as versões do SQL apesar de estar certa.

Comment: @MarcelodeAguiar Editei para deixar isso claro.

Answer (score 8):

Em T-SQL você pode usar o `IF` e o `EXISTS`. Exemplo:

```sql
DECLARE @D DATETIME
SET @D = GETDATE()
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM DatasBase WHERE DataBase = '2013-12-12')
    UPDATE DatasBase SET DataAtualizacao = @D WHERE DataBase = '2013-12-12'
ELSE 
    INSERT INTO DatasBase (DataBase, DataAtualizacao) VALUES ('2013-12-12', @D)
```

Answer (score 2):

Minha forma preferida de fazer isso é tentar atualizar e se ele não conseguir dai eu faço o insert. Acho que funciona em todas as versões de banco, eu já usei a partir do MSSQL 2005 sem problemas.

```sql
UPDATE DatasBase SET DataAtualizacao = @D WHERE DataBase = '2013-12-12'
IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
  INSERT INTO DatasBase (DataBase, DataAtualizacao) VALUES ('2013-12-12', @D)
```